# Random output from Myrrix for the same input

Tags: myrrix

I'm getting slightly different results each time I run Myrrix, even though I'm giving it the exact same input. (I'm only running the serving layer.)

Is this expected behavior and if so how much can I expect the results to vary?

My spontaneous guess would be that the algorithm Myrrix uses is inherently nondeterministic due to the fact that it's built to be massively parallelized --- would that be a correct assessment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not related to the parallelism, but to the random initial conditions of the algorithm. You will see slightly different solutions each time. While that's normal, they shouldn't be too different. If they are, that indicates over-fitting: you might have a lot of features, or low lambda, for your data set. My first guess is that your data set is fairly small and the default of 30 features is quite big in comparison.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about the random initial conditions. You are right, I was running the algorithm on a very small data set with the default parameters.